# Pass values to database with selectize multiselect

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, selectize.js

I have an "Add Employee" modal with a multiselect selectize "Department" dropdown. On button click, an ajax call will run to call respective controller and pass values to database. I can pass everything aside from the "Department" dropdown.

I have tried:

```
$.ajax({
...
data: { ..., Department: $("#cmbAddDepartment").val(), .... }
})


$.ajax({
...
data: { ...., Department: $("#cmbAddDepartment").getValue(), ... }
})
```

and

```
var selectize = $('#cmbAddDepartment').get(0).selectize;
var cmbAddDepartment=selectize.getValue();
$.ajax({
...
data: { ... , Department: cmbAddDepartment, ... }
})
```

Funny thing is, all those work inside an `alert()` but not inside an ajax data.

I am using:
Bootstrap 4 alpha 6,
JQuery 3.2.1,
Standalone Selectize 0.12.4

**EDIT:**
Just an fyi, all my other comboboxes are single-select (still selectize), and `$("#cmbAddSomething"`).val()` works for them.

**EDIT 2:** Here is the controller and (view)model

Viewmodel - vmEmpCreate.cs

```
public class vmEmpCreate
{
    public vmEmpCreate()
    {
        //constructor
    }

    //combo
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string[] Department { get; set; } //can be multiple
    public string ProductionLine { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AddCompany { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AddSite { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AddDepartment { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AddProductionLine { get; set; }

}

public class MyListSelectForAdd
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

Controller - Controller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEmployee(vmEmpCreate vmc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            modEmployee addemp = new modEmployee();

            addemp.Company = vmc.Company;
            addemp.Site = vmc.Site;
            addemp.Department = vmc.Department;
            ...
            addemp.Remarks = vmc.Remarks;

            conn = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            comm = new SqlCommand("insert into someTable (company, site, department, ..., remarks) values ('"
                + addemp.Company + "' , '"
                + addemp.Site + "' , '"
                + addemp.Department + "' , '"
                ...
                + addemp.Remarks + "')", conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```

**EDIT 3:** as per suggestions, i checked my program with chrome inspector to see any errors, but none came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a workaround for this problem by storing the multiselect dropdown selected values to a HiddenFor, and then passing that value to my "Department" property in the ajax call. I also changed my viewmodel "Department" property from an array to a string.

(View)Model:

```
public string Department;
```

View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Department, new { @id = "hdnDepartment" })

$('#btnAddEmployee').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectize = $('#cmbAddDepartment').get(0).selectize;
    var cmbAddDepartment = selectize.getValue();
    $("#hdnDepartment").val(cmbAddDepartment);
    $.ajax({
        ..
        data: { ..., Department: $("#hdnDepartment").val(), ... }, // optional data
        ...
    });
});
```

Pretty cheap solution, but it gets the job done.
Thanks to everyone with their help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with selectize, but in order to send the set of information you need to store it in an object (aka. associative array):

```
var selectize = $('#cmbAddDepartment').get(0).selectize;
var cmbAddDepartment=selectize.getValue();

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
        ... , 
        Department: cmbAddDepartment, 
        ...
    }
});
```

You can pass as much data as you need into that. So if all of your methods work, then use the one that is best for you, making sure that the data is enclosed in the brackets.

More on [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: oh! yes, i already did. just forgot to include it in the question. sorry, will edit now. thank you.

Comment: Okay. Have you checked to console to make sure the request is being sent? And can you show some of your server side code where you receive the request?

Comment: Yes, the other values gets saved to the database. when my code enters the controller, model.Department is always null. Sorry, can you clarify what you mean by server side code?

Comment: He is saying that are you sure that values are not getting passed in ajax request? Check your chrome inspector and make sure of that first. If values are getting passed then the problem is lying in the backend.

Comment: Is the backend written in C#? @ohno.morty That is the code we need to see since the JavaScript is not broken

Comment: i have edited my question to include backend code, please take a look. thank you

Comment: @Suraj the values are getting passed because the other properties of my viewmodel are filled. those passed values are successfully stored in my db. but that's because those are single-selects. the user input from my "Department" combobox cannot be passed when it's multi-select. upon entering the controller, myviewmodel.Department shows null